# Can't get custom css to cascade in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my first TB site and trying to understand how to customize the css.  I would rather not touch the bootstrap.css file, and instead have a mycustom.css file.  However, the cascade doesn't appear to be working, though I have it called in last in my  tag.  As a simple example: I want to change the color of the navbar link.  If I change it in the bootstrap.css file I can get it to work.  If I put the same style declarations in mycustom.css and change the colors there, it doesn't have any effect.  This is the css I'm referring to, but the case is the same with anything I try to customize.

`

```
.navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {

  color:#93a4bb;   /* light blue  */

}`
```

Is there something else in play that I am not understanding about TB?

Comment: Can you put your `<link ...>` codes in question?

Comment: Are you definitely calling your custom css file AFTER the bootstrap css file?

Comment: The CSS is valid as shown by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/eA9Wz/). Check with your web/network inspector (F12) that the file is loaded, that the right content is loaded, and in which order and finally the CSS inspector to check if it's applied.

Comment: as pointed out by @BillyMoat check that you call your css after the bootsrap.css. Also

Comment: I have a URL now: http://168.156.9.250/WELA/ The hover code I posted above is in the WELA.css file at the bottom.  File is on the server and other styles (my own) are being applied (see funky background image).

Comment: for some reason my background picture won't show up on the live site (though it does in local development), so I made a custom background color instead to confirm that my styles are being read in my custom css file